# Importing a flask-classy view outside of the project

Tags: python, flask, python-import

Good Day - similar Python 3 import issues and question that I have seen in google and on this site, but no answer to this type of situation.  How do I import a Flask-Classy view, from outside of the app?

Let's say I have a Flask app, on Python 3.6, using Flask-Classy and the structure looks something like:

```
MainFolder   
├── __init__.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── views
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── myview.py
│   │   └── config.py
│   ├── app.py
└── sideproj
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── calc.py
```

Now `myview.py` imports config through `from .config import Config` (Config being the classname within `config.py`). `myview.py` contains the main Class functions to work within the Flask framework but also has a `helper` function within the class that does the main work.  This is all good, and when I run `python app.py` - it is able to serve the Flask App and I can access it at `localhost:5000`.

Now my problem is, I am working on a side project that calculates some data and I want to use that core workhorse function within `myview.py` but outside of the flask app.  In `sideproj/calc.py` I essentially want to import that `myview.py` so I can run the function (currently sitting within the Class) without duplicating the code base.

Using an ugly hack the first thing I tried is:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../app/views')

import myview
```

The code is able to import `myview` but because `myview.py` is importing `config.py` it is not able to properly import it and gives me the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

I can't find a way to import `myview` with `config.py` and still be able to run `app.py` and serve the website.  For example, if I change the import in `myview.py` to just `import config`, then `calc.py` can run but `app.py` fails due to it's inability to import `Config`.

Is there a good way to do this? Or a way to re-organize that main workhorse function so it can be used by both `myview.py` and `calc.py` (and the functions reference values in `config`). Ideally I don't have the same code in two spots.

Comment: I would create a new package independent of your flask app and `sideproject` that contains the workhorse functionality. For example add a `workhorse_package` folder with a `setup.py` that you install with `pip install .` in the environment you're running your flask app in. Then you can import that functionality within the flask app and  sideproject code as needed but just maintain the functionality within the `workhorse_package`.

Comment: What does your `MainFolder/__init__.py` do?

Comment: Nothing. It's blank.  It was added on the advice to ensure that files in other folders could be added.

Comment: @ReilyBourne Please, write how you solved this issue, and if my answer helped, you can mark it so :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make the functionality you want to duplicate into the **package**, as @chris suggested in the comment:

> I would create a new package independent of your flask app and side-project that contains the workhorse functionality. For example, add a `workhorse_package` folder with a `setup.py` that you install with `pip install`. In the environment, you're running your flask app in. Then you can import that functionality within the flask app and side project code as needed but just maintain the functionality within the `workhorse_package`. @chris

2. You can use [Flask **blueprints**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/). Whether this is applicable depends on your app usage.
3. (Hacky way, not recommended for a serious app, but can be useful when developing multiple prototypes, using some shared functionality) You can move `myview.py` into `MainFolder/helpers/` and write a script that makes a copy into both projects when running them.
4. Don't. If you want to do this to keep DRY, you don't. These are two separate projects, they deserve separate files. Even now they are different - one uses some config, the other doesn't. Is it really that helpful?